# Why com.apple.screensaver.plist values are different in $prompt and #prompt

Tags: macos

When i give this command "defaults -currentHost read com.apple.screensaver" in $prompt, i get following output

```
macbook:~ macbook$  defaults -currentHost read com.apple.screensaver
{
    CleanExit = YES;
    PrefsVersion = 100;
    idleTime = 3600;
    moduleDict =     {
        moduleName = iLifeSlideshows;
        path = "/System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework/Resources/iLifeSlideshows.saver";
        type = 0;
    };
    tokenRemovalAction = 0;
}
```

and when i give same in #prompt(in root) i am getting different values

```
macbook:~ root#  defaults -currentHost read com.apple.screensaver
{
    askForPasswordDelay = 1800;
    idleTime = 3600;
}
```

Please some one explain me the difference

Comment: Even i am facing the same issue. Any support is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

(a) What are you doing logged in as root? (b) If the difference isn't obvious to you, then you shouldn't be logged in as root. (c) Userdefaults picks up defaults from different places, depending who the user is.

Comment: Response to a)I am logged as an particular user out of all user accounts                b)We can acess data only when we  get admin privillages( root mode)       c) So please help me to set this default value for particular user